# Set the destination path for an uploaded image in a flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I have made an application in flask which asks the user to upload an image, that image is being stored in a folder inside the static folder. I have specified the full local path in the code when I run that application locally to store that image. I want to deploy this application on IBM cloud. So, I can't write the path that I had set on my local machine. Any help what path should I give for the folder where the image is to be uploaded. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use absolute paths.

```
MYDIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.path.join(MYDIR + "/" + app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
```